# Python remove a key from dictionary when It's a number

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to iterate over a dictionary in order to delete all items where the key is a number.

```
dict= {'hello':'3', 'baby':'5', '33':'6'}

for k in dict.keys():
    if k.isdigit():
       del dict[k]
```

The result i need is this:

```
dict={'hello':'3', 'baby':'5'}
```

I use the code above but it doesn't work?
Can somebody help me?

Comment: That seems to work just fine when I run your code.  On a side note, naming your variables after basic python types (like `dict`) is at some point going to cause you grief.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of deleting items while looping through the dictionary, you can create a new dictionary:

```
dict_ = {'hello':'3', 'baby':'5', '33':'6'}

{k: v for k, v in dict_.items() if not k.isdigit()}
# {'baby': '5', 'hello': '3'}
```

Comment: Note: It won't delete the items in original `dict`. Instead return the new list with filtered content

Comment: But it is the better way

Answer (score 1):

The error `RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration`, as it said, is raised because the dictionnary is modified during the iteration. One solution could be to first register all the keys, then modify the dictionnary:

```
dict= {'hello':'3', 'baby':'5', '33':'6'}

for k in tuple(dict.keys()):  # iterate on a tuple of values that happened to be in dict's keys
    if k.isdigit():
       del dict[k]
```

The other, more pythonic, is to build the dictionnary in place, for instance using the dictionnary in intension notation like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41188409/3077939).

Btw, `dict` is a very bad name for an object of type `dict`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you are updating the dictionary while traversing. Rather first store the keys in a list and then remove from the dictionary.

Try this:

```
dic= {'hello':'3', 'baby':'5', '33':'6'}

x=dic.keys()
for k in x:
    if k.isdigit():
       del dic[k]
print dic
```

output :

```
{'baby': '5', 'hello': '3'}
```

Comment: This still doesn't work for for me in python 3. `x = list(dic.keys()) or tuple(dic.keys())` is probably the way to go(didn't down vote though).

Comment: this works in python 2. you didnt mention anywhere that you need it for python 3 specifically!

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution using `pop` and `map` to modify **in place** your initial dictionary:

```
my_dict = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, '11':4, '12':5} 
_ = map(lambda k: my_dict.pop(k), [k for k in my_dict if k.isdigit()])
# The map functions modifies in place your dictionary
```

Output :

```
>> my_dict
>> {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```